# batch for loop with bracket in the command

Tags: batch-file, scripting, escaping

I have a batch file with the following code:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d') do (
 echo Processing %%a >>%LOG%
 dtsrun /S(local) /NNotesLoad /A"FilePath:8="%NOTESDIR%\%%a" /AClientID=%1 >>%LOG%

 echo Deleting %%a >>%LOG%
 del %%a /q
)
```

This is returning an error message of "/NNotesLoad was unexpected at this time" because the second bracket is effectively closing the FOR block.

I have to leave the (local) as the /S parameter.
How do I escape the brackets in the dtsrun line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replaceing /S(local) with /S%computername% or /S. or /Slocalhost.  All of these should accomplish the same thing w/o using parens.

Alternatively, you can use the caret ^ to escape the parens:

dtsrun /S^(local^) ...

thanks,
mark

Comment: the caret was the solution for escaping the brackets. thanks

Answer (score 2):

At the possible loss of some readability, you can put all those commands on the same line and do away with the need for brackets in your for loop.

```
for blah blah blah do command 1 && command 2 && command 3 && command 4
```